# Error when updating from angular 7 to Angular 8.0.0-beta.7 with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap in my Angular 7 project and I wanted to update to 8.0.0-beta.7 just to check out the new version but I am getting an error from the ngx-bootstrap timepicker component

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/type'.
```

Is there any way I can do something about this so that I can check out the new Angular 8 Beta.

Answer (score 3):

Already when you install `ngx-bootstrap` to Angular 8.0-beta warning appears.

```
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed...
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed...
```

At this time you are not able to run the application without error because the structure has changed in Angular 8.

For example:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor'.`

The `src` directory doesn't exist there anymore now it can be imported from this path 
`@angular/forms`

**What can you do with it.**

Stay at Angular 7.x.x - stable and wait for ngx-bootstrap update

**Or**

> After updating few paths where were the errors it started working. But I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Update ngx-bootstrap in package.json

"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",

Then run 'npm install'